# How do I identify a DELL PERC RAID controller?

Tags: windows-server-2003, raid, dell, dell-perc

I have a PERC RAID Controller (PCI-X) installed in a Dell Precision 670 workstation running Windows Server 2003.  The controller is hooked up to a PowerVault 221S.  The system sees the card as a "RAID Controller" (unknown).  I have tried all known drivers available on the Precision 670 support downloads, and none work.  I also vaguely recall the card to be a PERC 6/i based on a previous setup, but I have tried those drivers as well with no luck.  How can I identify this card?

** EDIT **
I took a *bad* pic of what the card displays on system boot:
[image]

Comment: If you go into the BIOS by doing a Control + H do you get any more info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the pic, it's definitely a PERC card (PowerEdge Expandable RAID Controller). What's in question is which PERC card it is. Reboot the system and press CTRL+M when you see this message to go into the controller configuration utility, which may identify the card for you. Short of that, and barring any other information displayed during POST, you may need to remove the card in order to identify it visually.

Comment: This worked.  You have to kinda dig for the right menu, but it's there.  Turns out it's a PERC 4/SC.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**
Based on the picture, it looks like it says its a PERC 320

**ORIGINAL MESSAGE:**
On a system reboot it seems like you should see it pass by when loading.

You could also install the [OpenManage Server Administrator](http://www.dell.com/content/topics/global.aspx/sitelets/solutions/management/server_monitor?c=us&cs=AIA&l=en&s=bsd#dellopenmanage) tools from Dell. I bet that would tell you.

Comment: I thought 320 just stood for max possible speed of the SCSI Ultra320 bus.  I searched for "PERC 320" and came up with a lot of cards that seem to use the Adaptec chipset, not LSI.

Comment: I would guess it's a rebranded LSI MegaRaid 320

Comment: Tried the driver for that & no-go.

Comment: Ok, so I think we've confirmed that it's a PERC 320 though (The original question). So now what's the issue with the driver you're installing? Also, what version of Windows Server 2003 are you using, 32 or 64bit?

Answer (score 0):

As nutty or simple as this sounds - If you visit dell and place in the Dell Service Tag for the system it will let you know which one you have installed (if it came with the system)

Since this is Windows - having dell scan your system should work as well.

Both are free - AND avoid a very long support call.

Comment: It did not come with the system, and I no longer have the original system.